# NoSuchMethodException in Gson JsonArray

Tags: java, gson

So I have stumbled on this error, whenever I try to remove an element from a JsonArray object, i get the NoSuchMethodException. But after looking at it for a solid day, i cannot find the reason for it. The method exists in the compiled .class file in the .jar file that is included in my project. And I'm at loss now. Surely the problem is between the chair and keyboard, but I just don't see it

EDIT: after compiling the project i don't get this error, so this has to do something with how eclipse is managing dependencies, because one project does use gson-2.2.4

I'm using [gson 2.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3) jar which I included via maven and even downloaded the jar file itself.

Example piece of code where the error is thrown:

```
else if (current.isJsonObject() && hasBucket(current)) {
    JsonElement buckets = current.getAsJsonObject().get(BUCKETS);
    JsonElement next = null;
    if (buckets.isJsonArray() && buckets.getAsJsonArray().size()>0) {
        JsonArray arr = buckets.getAsJsonArray();
        arr.remove(0); //<--- exception is thrown here
    } else if (buckets.isJsonObject()) {
        Set<Entry<String,JsonElement>> entrySet = buckets.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entrySet) {
            next = entry.getValue();
            buckets.getAsJsonObject().remove(entry.getKey());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

when i compile my project using maven i can see that maven is using gson 2.3

```
[INFO] Expanding: /Users/####/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3/gson-2.3.jar into /Users/####/Documents/workspace/proj_name/target/assembly/work/gson-2.3.jar
```

output of `javap ~/Downloads/gson-2.3/com/google/gson/JsonArray.class` from the jar file that is in classpath of my java project

```
Compiled from "JsonArray.java"
public final class com.google.gson.JsonArray extends com.google.gson.JsonElement implements java.lang.Iterable {
  public com.google.gson.JsonArray();
  com.google.gson.JsonArray deepCopy();
  public void add(com.google.gson.JsonElement);
  public void addAll(com.google.gson.JsonArray);
  public com.google.gson.JsonElement set(int, com.google.gson.JsonElement);
  public boolean remove(com.google.gson.JsonElement);
  public com.google.gson.JsonElement remove(int); <---- It exists!
  public boolean contains(com.google.gson.JsonElement);
  public int size();
  public java.util.Iterator iterator();
  public com.google.gson.JsonElement get(int);
  public java.lang.Number getAsNumber();
  public java.lang.String getAsString();
  public double getAsDouble();
  public java.math.BigDecimal getAsBigDecimal();
  public java.math.BigInteger getAsBigInteger();
  public float getAsFloat();
  public long getAsLong();
  public int getAsInt();
  public byte getAsByte();
  public char getAsCharacter();
  public short getAsShort();
  public boolean getAsBoolean();
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public int hashCode();
  com.google.gson.JsonElement deepCopy();
}
```

Comment: How about a stack trace?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.JsonArray.remove(I)Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;` this is the whole stacktrace, then there are just the java files in my project and no ther indication

Comment: Which ide do you use? If you are working on Eclipse,can you open "Open Type" dialog (on mac: cmd+shift+t, windows: ctrl+shift+t) and write com.google.gson.JsonArray then see the jar/jars?

Comment: I use eclipse. If I cmd+click on the remove function it takes me to gson-2.3.jar and when i try to find it via cmd+shift+t I can see the included 2.3 version of gson

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with your build setup.

[`JsonArray.remove(int)`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#remove-int-) was introduced in version 2.3 of Gson. Most likely what is happening is you are compiling against the correct version (2.3), but the version that is getting packaged in your APK is not the correct version.

Comment: i will have to check the JsonArray.class file in my packaged jar, but i wonder how this could have happened because the gson-2.3 was used since the start of development and has not been changed.

Comment: Check your import statements and/or any other libraries you use. Often times third-party libraries will also bundle Gson along with their library and leave its accessibility public. You may be accidentally importing an alternate implementation of Gson that way.

Comment: it will have to do with eclipse, it's probably confusing two versions of gson, since the maven build of the project does not have this error

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify a collection you're iterating.

Apart of avoiding the abuse of calling toThis and toThat, you should iterate the collection and insert in a result one when necessary and then assign the whole thing. One of the elements go null after you've removed a previous one or so.

Comment: the problem is i can't think of a better way of iterating over a very complex json with multiple nested json/array objects and the keys are used as a descriptor of content, and i need to create a tree out of this json :(

Comment: Or is there a way to iterate over every JsonElement like a tree?

Comment: Be that as it may, the error occurs in a part of the code where there is no iteration.

Comment: I do still belive he´s removing one item and the next one is an empty node. You should get the list, create another one and, instead of removing objects from the first, go adding the valid to the new one. Then, flush or wipe the original list and insert the results you want to keep.

Comment: or, as I see, there´s no condition for removal, so just, run the list, and AFTER the loop, wipe the list, but don´t remove elements because the iterator is backed up by the list you´re running